# How to log react console errors to a file?

Tags: reactjs, error-logging

I am new in front-end/client-side app development for website. I am setting up a new react project. I used `create-react-app`.

How should I handle the console errors(other than network call errors)? Is there a way to log them in any file?

What are the best logging practices?

Comment: Welcome to stack! Since React is a client side library, the errors are occurring on someone else's browser, and browsers for obvious reasons can't write files to computers, let alone *your* computer. You could however make a POST request on errors somewhere and then log them there

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do that anyways. What purpose does the file have over, say, just fixing the errors during development?

Comment: @azium got your points. I have updated my question. Can you have a relook?

Answer (score 5):

Even though there are means and ways to store data on the browser (not to actual client files) that's not really the general strategy for logging browser errors (which I believe is what you're referring to).

In my experience we'd have a dedicated logging server with a simple API with adequate security that filters traffic and applies rate limiting. That would finally enhance and write logs into a document database that can later be analysed.

A naive JavaScript solution would be using the following to capture errors and send them out to a logging server.

```
window.onerror = function(message, url, lineNumber) {  
  // make ajax call to api to save error on server
  return true;
};
```

I should also mention `Sentry.io` - they provide a service that does this and even though there are some limitations they're usually enough for a small to mid app.

https://github.com/getsentry

[image]

Comment: I was thinking about sentry as well. :+1:

Comment: @jeanfrg I have updated my quesion, Can you have a relook?

Comment: @RahulKumar my answer still stands. Basically what something like sentry does is capture all console errors and them makes an ajax call to an api which will save them for you to be able to check them out at a later date.

Comment: @RahulKumar I've updated the answer with screenshots, links and a code snippet

Comment: @RahulKumar did this help?